# Creating a Lambda@Edge : Why did I get a CloudFront error (IllegalUpdate)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I'm new to Lambda@Edge and I tried to create one using the AWS tutorial but when I try to deploy to Lambda@Edge I get this error :

[image]

I restarted the process many times but always get this. Is there something wrong with the cloudfront distribution's settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I didn't resolve this error and I still don't know where it comes from.

However, I've been able to add the Cloudfront trigger to the Lambda using the Cloudfront Console and not the Lambda Console.